# Find a property value in the list of objects in scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

```
 class Student {
  var name: String = _
  var stId: String = _
  var courseName: String = _
}

object Student {
  def apply(name: String, stId: String, courseName: String): Student = {
    var s = new Student
    s.name = name
    s.stId = stId
    s.courseName = courseName
    s
  }
}

val studentList :MutableList[Student]= MutableList()
studentList+=(Student("Alex","TI178","Math"))
studentList+=(Student("Bob","TI654","Comp"))
studentList+=(Student("Sam","TI1115","Comp"))
studentList+=(Student("Don","TI900","Math"))
```

how to find the list of student.stId who enrolled in "Math" or given value in the above MutableList?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
studentList.filter(_.courseName=="Math").map(_.stId)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell without knowing what exactly a `MutableList` is. But assuming it's a `scala.collection.mutable.MutableList` you can do something like this:

```
studentList.collect { 
  case s if s.courseName == "Math" => s.stId 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the students who enrolled in a given course you can use the `filter` function, which creates a new collection with only the elements for which the given function returns `true`:

```
studentList.filter(_.courseName == "Math")
```

then, to get the ids, you can use `map`, which returns a new collection by applying the given function to each element and collecting the results:

```
studentList.filter(_.courseName == "Math").map(_.stId)
```

Answer (score 0):

With collect, you just traverse the collection just once and you can achieve the desire result that you want!

```
studentList.collect { 
  case student if student.courseName == "Math" => student.stId 
}
```

So effectively collect is filter and map in just one step!